# Sending Multiple Asyncronous PHP cURL requests

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP cURL to and it is returning a json response. What I want to be able to do is send multiple requests at the same time to test the program to make sure it can handle multiple requests simultaneously. At the moment I am trying with the below code:-

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {

    var MAXNUM = 9;

    function newAsyncRequest() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var val = Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAXNUM+1));
            if (val !== 0)
                newAsyncRequest();
            console.log(val);
        }, 1000);
    }

    newAsyncRequest();

});


function asyncFunction(session) {
    (new Request({
        url: test.php,
        onComplete: function (response) {

            // Do something???

        }
    })).get();
}
```

**PHP**

```
function sendPostcodeRequest() {

    require_once('scripts/php/controllers/curl.controller.php');

    $postcode = 'LE11 3SA';
    $postcode = rawurlencode($postcode);

    $uri = 'http://192.168.1.110:8290/?pc='.$postcode; // Home

    $response = CurlController::request($uri);

}
```

Basically I am wanting to run `sendPostcodeRequest();` PHP say 1000 times asynchronously.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can try it with a benchmark tool. i.e. ab -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html there you can make concurent connections etc.